# Single Activity with multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I m new to Android development and stuck with design. I d like to design a single activity application with multiple fragments. But whatever I consider, I m stuck with design.
I first considered fragments as components or widgets that I could organize where I wanted on my screen. But a single activity has only one xml view layout and can not find a solution.

Here is what I want.

[UI design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmOfy.png)

The problems are the following.

1. The layout choice: I need a layout for full screen fragment screen 1 but another splitted one for other screens.
2. The keyboard: if I do a fullscreen fragment layout for all my screens with a (game-keyboard) fragment and (dico-keyboard) fragment, how do I remove the keyboard in dico fragment on tablets ? And can I share keyboard code between both fragments ?

I saw that calling setContentView during runtime is kinda annoying as you have to reassign your variables and is not suitable.
All the applications I find are fullscreen single fragment on layout allowing libs like ViewPager. I can not find an example of composed screen with fragment components.

What layout would you chose, with what kind of fragments ?
Or do you know a library that allow composing fragments as widgets on screen ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Finaly, I will use system keyboard. It makes single fragment per screen. No more problem

Comment: I found a solution to this design. Single activity, three host fragments to handle screenconfig and have only fullscreen fragments for pageViwer. And nested fragments for my components. I now have a keyboard that I can colorate, modify and do what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Android.  Buckle up, it's going to be a bumpy ride.

First, you should spend some quality time with the Android Developer Guides.

[Developer Guides | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide)

The insight for your particular challenge is that layouts are *resources*, and and you can have a layout resource that changes based on the *configuration*.

So for example, you could have a resource like `layout_main` with one XML file for small devices and a different XML file for large devices.

[App resources overview | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources)

[Create alternate layouts | Support different screen sizes | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes#alternative-layouts)

You can arrange fragments on a layout using the Android Studio layout designer.

Comment: Thx for the reply. I am ok with differents screen size and layouts. I see how to configure phones/tablets difference. My problem is keyboard fragment design. Without keyboard fragment, design would be OK.

Comment: In Android it's referred to as an *Input Method Editor* (IME).  The philosophy they want you to use is that it's up to the user/system if an IME is displayed/used.  Keyboards are not the only kind of IME.  So you design to make the UI work regardless if the IME is displayed or not.  This is a little controversial because most developers like yourself want to know what the whole screen is going to look like.

Comment: My app need special character and it would have been easier for users to have what they need on screen. So you think it s better to let android take care of keyboard and design a single fullscreen fragment on screen. It would greatly simplify the design indeed.

Comment: Is there a way to have a custom keyboard for the app ? It would solve my problem.

Comment: Sure, the keys are just buttons inside a layout container.  Ideally, you wouldn't want to have to rewrite an IME, but depending on the application it might make sense.

Comment: For example, the New York Times Wordle web app has a custom keyboard, rather then having a text entry that pops up the platform keyboard.  That's HTML and script rather than native Android, but the design principle is there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Fragments and navigate.

First of all yu need a navigation: In the left hand side on Android Studio you can find the **Resource Manager** Then click to **Navigation** then click to **+** and choose the **Navigation resource file**

After this you can add fragment to the navigation:
New Destination (green +) (Don't forget to give name to your fragments).

After this you can add the navigation to your activity's xml. You should use the `app:menu=”@menu/bottom_nav_menu”` code in your xml

Here a video about the process:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Chso6xrJ6aU

Comment: Thx for the reply. Interesting. But this is a solution for one fragment per page once again.